# Is there a way to pass logic in JSP without form tag?

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets

I want to have navigation and  tag to send user to their cart_overview.jsp(shopping cart) like this:

```
  <body>
    <nav>                       
       <a href="cart_overview.jsp">Cart</a>
    </nav>
</body>
```

When i leave it like that it will go to the cart but it will always be empty since i must do `select query on cart`. Then i change it to this:

```
  <body>
    <nav>
        <form action="cartservlet" method="GET">
            <button type="submit">Cart</button>
        </form>                     
    </nav>
  </body>
```

But i don't want to have a button in navigation, is there a way to have `<a>` tag or something similar? And is this a proper way of using form?

Comment: You need to get `cart-id`  in your next page you mean?

Comment: @Swati  Well yeah cart-id and every article that is in `cart`.

Comment: Store `card-id` in sessions as i have  told already,so that you can use anywhere.

Comment: @Swati I know that, i didn't ask that exactly, what about button in nav bar? How can i change it?

Comment: You can design your button in such a way it look like `a` tag not `button` using `css`.Sorry if i missunderstood something :) .

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yes! perfect. Thank you